# Does anybody know how to center the availability calendar from availabilitycalendar.com

Tags: calendar

Does anybody know how to center the availability calendar from availabilitycalendar.com as the standard one always pulls to the left. I have contacted the developers but they said I need to use CSS to do so. I am struggling with this.

https://www.availabilitycalendar.com/